# Как отправить письмо с php with mail()

Tags: php, email

Такая форма:

```html
<form action="main.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="user_phone" placeholder="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Оставить заявку" />
</form>
```

и такой `main.php`

```php
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

    if (isset($_POST["user_phone"])) {
        $user_phone = $_POST["user_phone"];
        echo "user phone is set";
        echo "<br />";
    }
    else 
        exit();
    $message = "$user_phone - user phone";
    mail('my.email@mail.ru', 'My Subject', $message);
    echo "ready";
```

На странице вывод такой:

```
user phone is set
ready
```

Но письмо не приходит на почту. Не могу понять в чем дело, может вы сможете найти ошибку

Comment: Существует множество причин, по которым ваш скрипт не отправляет электронные письма. Это трудно диагностировать, если нет явной синтаксической ошибки. Парвильно ли настроен ваш хостинг на исходящие сообщения, открыты ли порты и тд.

Comment: Еще неплохо было бы заглянуть в очередь заданий почтового сервера

Comment: Добавьте проверку `if(mail('ваши данные')){ echo 1; }else{ echo 2; }` Если выполнится 2 условие, значит на хостинге запрещено использование функции mail(). Тогда используйте, скажем, PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Если так попробовать?

```
$mailheaders = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$mailheaders .= "From: test@test.com\r\n";
mail('my.email@mail.ru', 'My Subject', $message, $mailheaders);
```